# ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key, Python

Tags: python, pandas

I a trying to write a program in Python and I am getting the following error:

```
raise ValueError("Cannot index with multidimensional key")
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

The error occurs when I call this function:

```
def pd_remove_condition(data,row,conditions):

for i in range(len(conditions)):
    data = data.loc[data[row] != conditions[i]]

return data
```

This function is called several times and only errors on one occasion. The data is dataframe that is imported from a simple csv. I have `"Significant Smoker"`, `"Current Smoker"` and `"Heavy Drinker"` columns that I use to calculate the column `"Heavy Smoker or Drinker"`:

```
adjusted_data["Smoker"] = np.where(adjusted_data["Significant Smoker"]=="No","Not at all",adjusted_data["Current Smoker"])
adjusted_data["Smoker"] = np.where(np.logical_or(adjusted_data["Smoker"]=="Not asked or Missing",adjusted_data["Smoker"]=="DonÂ´t Know/Not Sure"),"Unknown", adjusted_data["Smoker"])
adjusted_data["Smoker"] = np.where(adjusted_data["Smoker"]=="Refused","Unknown", adjusted_data["Smoker"])
adjusted_data["Heavy Smoker or Drinker"] = np.where(np.logical_or(adjusted_data["Smoker"]=="Every day",adjusted_data["Heavy Drinker"]==2),True, False)
adjusted_data["Heavy Smoker or Drinker"] = np.where(np.logical_and(adjusted_data["Smoker"]!="Every day",adjusted_data["Heavy Drinker"]==9),"Unknown",adjusted_data["Heavy Smoker or Drinker"] )
adjusted_data["Heavy Smoker or Drinker"] = np.where(np.logical_and(adjusted_data["Smoker"]=="Unknown",adjusted_data["Heavy Drinker"]!=2),"Unknown",adjusted_data["Heavy Smoker or Drinker"] )
```

When I try to run `pd_remove_condition`, I am only trying to remove records with `"Unknown"` in the `"Heavy Smoker or Drinker"` Column, i.e. `row = "Heavy Smoker or Drinker"` and `conditions = ["Unknown"]`.

Since the function works properly in other circumstances, it makes me think that the issue is with the creation of the `["Heavy Smoker or Drinker"]` column above. In creating it, perhaps I have accidentally made a multi-dimensional column? I'm a Python noob and I'm kind of stumped as how to solve this. All help is appreciated!

Kind regards,

C

EDIT:

Here is a copy of the column once created when using.to_csv:

```
Heavy Smoker or Drinker
False
False
False
False
False
True
False
False
False
False
False
Unknown
False
False
False
False
False
```

I am trying to workout why feeding this through `pd_remove_condition` results in an error rather than removing the `"unknowns"`

Comment: To get help faster, give you sample data and expected output. People tend not to read code plus there is always multiple ways to reach a desired outcome.

Comment: When you [caught the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspected/printed relevant data in the except suite - was there anything obviously wrong?

Comment: If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features. Printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening. 
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)